# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, youtube, download

Can somebody help me with this code? I'm trying to make a python script that will play videos and I found this file that download's Youtube videos. I am not entirely sure what is going on and I can't figure out this error.

Error:

```python
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Traceback:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube.py", line 67, in <module>
    videoUrl = getVideoUrl(content)
  File "youtube.py", line 11, in getVideoUrl
    grps = fmtre.group(0).split('&amp;')
```

Code snippet:

(lines 66-71)

```python
content = resp.read()
videoUrl = getVideoUrl(content)

if videoUrl is not None:
    print('Video URL cannot be found')
    exit(1)
```

(lines 9-17)

```python
def getVideoUrl(content):
    fmtre = re.search('(?<=fmt_url_map=).*', content)
    grps = fmtre.group(0).split('&amp;')
    vurls = urllib2.unquote(grps[0])
    videoUrl = None
    for vurl in vurls.split('|'):
        if vurl.find('itag=5') > 0:
            return vurl
    return None
```

Comment: @omouse Do you want to see all of my code? The question has been answered

Comment: I'm obviously trying to learn, no need to be so critical

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The error is in your line 11, your `re.search` is returning no results, ie `None`, and then you're trying to call `fmtre.group` but `fmtre` is `None`, hence the `AttributeError`.

You could try:

```
def getVideoUrl(content):
    fmtre = re.search('(?<=fmt_url_map=).*', content)
    if fmtre is None:
        return None
    grps = fmtre.group(0).split('&amp;')
    vurls = urllib2.unquote(grps[0])
    videoUrl = None
    for vurl in vurls.split('|'):
        if vurl.find('itag=5') > 0:
            return vurl
    return None
```

Comment: This works. For some reason it doesn't recognize the URL now. Time to figure that out...

Answer (score 6):

You use `regex` to match the url, but it can't match, so the result is `None`

and `None` type doesn't have the `group` attribute

You should add some code to `detect` the result

If it can't match the rule, it should not go on under code

```
def getVideoUrl(content):
    fmtre = re.search('(?<=fmt_url_map=).*', content)
    if fmtre is None:
        return None         # if fmtre is None, it prove there is no match url, and return None to tell the calling function 
    grps = fmtre.group(0).split('&amp;')
    vurls = urllib2.unquote(grps[0])
    videoUrl = None
    for vurl in vurls.split('|'):
        if vurl.find('itag=5') > 0:
            return vurl
    return None
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to mention the newly [**`walrus` operator**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) in this context because this question is marked as a duplicate quite often and the operator may solve this very easily.

---

Before `Python 3.8` we needed:

```
match = re.search(pattern, string, flags)
if match:
    # do sth. useful here
```

As of `Python 3.8` we can write the same as:

```
if (match := re.search(pattern, string, flags)) is not None:
    # do sth. with match
```

Other languages had this before (think of `C` or `PHP`) but imo it makes for a cleaner code.

---

For the above code this could be

```
def getVideoUrl(content):
    if (fmtre := re.search('(?<=fmt_url_map=).*', content)) is None:
        return None
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

just wanted to add to the answers, a group 
of data is expected to be in a sequence, so you can 
match each section of the grouped data without 
skipping over a data because if a word is skipped from a 
sentence, we may not refer to the sentence as one group anymore, see the below example for more clarification, however, the compile method is deprecated.

```
msg = "Malcolm reads lots of books"

#The below code will return an error.

book = re.compile('lots books')
book = re.search(book, msg)
print (book.group(0))

#The below codes works as expected

book = re.compile ('of books')
book = re.search(book, msg)
print (book.group(0))

#Understanding this concept will help in your further 
#researchers. Cheers.
```