# Regular expressions in Python - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex

I;m trying to print out the file names that start with the word `first`.

Here's what I have done:

import os
import re

```
path = '/my_path'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        match_pattern = re.search(r'^first', file)
        print match_pattern.group()
```

But, here's what I got when running the program:

```
first
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print match_pattern.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I would like to print out the file names that start with `first`, as follows for instance:

```
first-xyz
first abc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That `match_pattern` is `None` means your regular expression doesn't match the filename.  Why not use a debugger and see what the value of `file` is?

Comment: I tried to print out "file" and got the file names returned

Comment: Why would you ever use regex for this? Just use `str.startswith`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080078/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your search is returning None. Try this instead :

```
path = '/my_path'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith("first"):
        print file + '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

If the RegEx doesn't match, it returns `None`, so you need to fix like this:

```
match_pattern = re.search(r'^first', file)
if match_pattern:
    print match_pattern.group()
```

Also, note that in Python 2, `file` is a built-in function (alias of `open`), you should not redefine.

Answer (score 0):

Python's regex methods `re.search()` and `re.match()` both return `None` if there is no match ([see python.org documentation for re.search() here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)). You need to test if the result is None before trying to access information on the results using `match_pattern.group()`.