# Odd "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

This might be a pretty obvious error since I'm pretty new to coding, but I'm trying to read a file for a certain value which I'll gather by using re.search and splice since I only know the text before and after it.

I'm running into a bit of an annoying bug. When I use re.search(r"firstPart(.*?)secondPart", data).group(1) it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Which is a problem with this line:

```
englishWord = re.search(r"<i>(.*?)</i>", str(englishWord)).group(1)
```

If you read the code, you can see that I've made some unnecessary lines where instead of writing the entire string in the re.search function I'll use only a little bit then add or remove text in another function. This is because if I do it all in the re.search function normally it doesn't work.

Possibly the most annoying part and confusing about this is that if I run everything before "englishWord = re.search(r"*(.*?)*", str(englishWord)).group(1)" then I run it, it works, but if I run all of the code at once I get that error. Any idea why? How can I fix this? Thanks! (I am using python 3.6)

My Code vvv

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

import re
import itertools

with open('Desktop/data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')

num = 0

for x in itertools.repeat(None, 8):
    num = int(num) + 1
    if int(num) < 10:
        num = '0' + str(num)
    firstString = re.search(r"id=\"question_" + num + "_whole_question\" data-sidebar-reference=\"\">    (.*?) <input", data).group(1)
    secondString = re.search(r"id=\"question_" + num + "_wol_1\"(.*?)  </div>", data).group(1)
    secondString = secondString.replace(" name=\"question_" + num + "_wol_1\" onchange=\"has_unsaved_work();\" size=\"10\" type=\"text\" />", "")
    finalString = firstString + " _" + secondString
    englishWord = re.search(r"(<i><span lang=\"en-US\">(.*?)</span></i>)", finalString)
    englishWord = re.search(r"<i>(.*?)</i>", str(englishWord)).group(1)
    englishWord = "<i>" + englishWord + "</i>"
    finalString = finalString.replace(englishWord, "")
    finalString = finalString.replace("()", "")
    print (finalString)
```

Comment: re.search() returns None if there was no match.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080078/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)

Comment: Seems like you are trying to use regex to parse html. Please don't, use beautiful soup. read this for why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call group only if there is a match.

```
res = re.search(r"<i>(.*?)</i>", str(englishWord))
# if there is a match
if res:
   englishWord = res.group(1)
```

As pointed out in the comments, `re.search` returns None when no match is found. Link : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how would this explain the fact that will work but only if you run all the previous lines first then compile them before you run that one?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you are asking.. but I will advise you to not use regex for html parsing. There is beautiful soup. Please use that. You won't have these kind of problems then.

Comment: Please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags